Why do the Sages often believe that the word רוב mean "majority," when it clearly means "a lot"?
It seems clear that the word רוב in biblical Hebrew means "a large amount." For example, Bereshit 48:16

וְיִדְגּוּ לָרֹב בְּקֶרֶב הָאָרֶץ may they teem into multitudes in the midst of the earth

certainly does not mean the descendants of Ephraim and Menashe should be the "majority" of the world (although in theory it could), but that they should be many. The same meaning is clearly implied in Devarim 1:10, "וְהִנְּכֶם הַיּוֹם כְּכוֹכְבֵי הַשָּׁמַיִם לָרֹב." It may be pronounced differently, but this is clearly the same word in Bamidbar 13:18 "הֶחָזָק הוּא הֲרָפֶה הַמְעַט הוּא אִם רָב" or 22:3 "וַיָּגׇר מוֹאָב מִפְּנֵי הָעָם מְאֹד כִּי רַב הוּא" and in many, many (a "multitude", one might say) other places in Tanakh.
Yet, in some of these instances, the Sages seem to read the word as if it means "a majority," as in, the larger part of a whole. The most famous example is Shemos 23:2 "לֹֽא־תִהְיֶ֥ה אַחֲרֵֽי־רַבִּ֖ים לְרָעֹ֑ת וְלֹא־תַעֲנֶ֣ה עַל־רִ֗ב לִנְטֹ֛ת אַחֲרֵ֥י רַבִּ֖ים לְהַטֹּֽת" (which is a difficult reading for other reasons, as Rashi and the commentators note there). But it also comes up elsewhere, such as in Megillah 16b:

כִּי מׇרְדֳּכַי הַיְּהוּדִי מִשְׁנֶה לַמֶּלֶךְ אֲחַשְׁוֵרוֹשׁ וְגָדוֹל לַיְּהוּדִים וְרָצוּי לְרוֹב אֶחָיו לְרוֹב אֶחָיו {אסתר י׳:ג׳} וְלֹא לְכׇל אֶחָיו מְלַמֵּד שֶׁפֵּירְשׁוּ מִמֶּנּוּ מִקְצָת סַנְהֶדְרִין.

Rambam even appears to have a novel biblical reading based upon this assumption in the beginning of Hil. Teshuvah Ch. 3:

אדם שעונותיו מרובין על זכיותיו, מיד הוא מת ברשעו, שנאמר ״על רוב עונך״ (ירמיהו ל׳:י״ד). וכן מדינה שעונותיה מרובין, מיד היא אובדת, שנאמר ״זעקת סדם ועמורה כי רבה״ (בראשית י״ח:כ׳). וכן כל העולם כולו, אם היו עונותיהם מרוביןא, מיד הן נשחתין, שנאמר ״וירא י״י כי רבה רעת האדם בארץ״ (בראשית ו׳:ה׳):

The question is, how are these readings justified if the word "Rov" clearly means multitude?
Possible answers might be (1) there is at least one instance in Tanakh where the context indicates that the word must mean "majority" and cannot be interpreted otherwise or (2) in these particular instances, there is some other hint in the text that motivated these rabbinic readings?
[And yes I know that this question has some methodological assumptions that might not be universally accepted]

Words can have more than one meaning and the context is important

It needn't be the case that the connotation of strict majority be present in all of רַבִּים רַב and רֹב. Meaning be careful not to automatically conflate the different forms.

@DoubleAA I agree, and a demonstration/reasoning why the form of רב of Shemos 23 would be different than that of Devarim 1 would be a very acceptable answer (and I have a theory about this but I'm no expert on grammar, and it certainly doesn't fit with Rambam)

I think the basis for interpretations like לרוב אחיו ולא לכל אחיו is that 1) the concept of "majority" is just the comparative of the concept of "being numerous" (compare the meaning of רוב whenever it has a comparative sense, e.g. לא מרבכם מכל העמים, רבו משערות ראשי); 2) the concept of numerousness doesn't imply totality, and 3) the verse chose רוב when it could have said כל (as it could have been expected to - why say "lots of people liked him" instead of "everyone liked him"? - unlike כְּכוֹכְבֵי הַשָּׁמַיִם לָרֹב where "all" is meaningless). Compare: יש לי רב - יש לי כל (Bereshit 33:9-11).

Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15845/759
